# Optimising very slow MySQL queries or tables on heavy traffic website

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm having problems with a few very slow MySQL database query that took down our site due to time-out issues (see SQL). Hopefully someone who is familiar with the inner-workings of MySQL will identify the problem easily.

#### Potential cause

I believe that the problem stems from the table design from our e-commerce platform.

The primary key in the `tbl_sessions` table is a VARCHAR(32).

Please correct me if I am wrong, but does MySQL not first scan the table's PRIMARY KEYs before inserting a new row to make sure that there are no duplications? I think this may be one of the problems when a new row is added to the `tbl_sessions` (see INSERT query below)

In the garbage collection process that is run regularly (see the DELETE query below) the two tables are joined and the `tbl_carts` rows that do not have joining sessions are deleted. There is no index to easily join them so I think MySQL is having to perform nested loops to make the join the tables (Rows_examined: 45718650). Is this correct?

#### Possible solutions

I am thinking of first making `tbl_sessions` a MyISAM table to remove the table locking issue on a constantly accessed and changing table.

Then I will adjust the table structure and PHP handling of `tbl_sessions` to use an "int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment" as the PRIMARY KEY instead of the current VARCH(32) generated via a random seed.

Adding an index to the `tbl_sessions`.`cart_id` could help MySQL make the join statement perform faster if there is an index to use.

#### Big question

Will these changes alleviate the issues our MySQL server is having when performing these queries?

I wanted to collect some ideas before altering the database and potentially causing more issues.

Many thanks in advance to people who read this and can provide any insight into the issue.

#### Sample data

In my slow queries log I have these entries (I have obfuscated some information):

```
User@Host: my_db[my_db] @  [111.111.111.168]  
Thread_id: 27062158  Schema: my_db  
Query_time: 35.360792  Lock_time: 0.000028  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0    Rows_affected: 1  Rows_read: 2  
INSERT INTO `tbl_sessions` (`session_id`, `member_id`, `fingerprint`, `cart_id`,   `expires`) VALUES ('b6792e10a652c951725a2f4ed42785b5', 0, '6398399acb7d1cbf8f47a01bdbfd7c4b78137e64', 99811, 1321259075);

User@Host: my_db[my_db] @  [111.111.111.108]  
  # Thread_id: 27062280  Schema: my_db  
  # Query_time: 35.360284  Lock_time: 0.000037  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0    Rows_affected: 1  Rows_read: 2  
  INSERT INTO `tbl_sessions` (`session_id`, `member_id`, `fingerprint`, `cart_id`, `expires`) VALUES ('a55b2259f779d7afe741d4aec52512d5', 0, '18c3d7525633a1420f9e4c396c35a8f70d16d8a2', 99822, 1321259075);  

User@Host: my_db[my_db] @  [111.111.111.109]  
Thread_id: 27062243  Schema: my_db  
Query_time: 35.360519  Lock_time: 0.000042  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0  Rows_affected: 1  Rows_read: 2  
INSERT INTO `tbl_sessions` (`session_id`, `member_id`, `fingerprint`, `cart_id`, `expires`) VALUES ('231b4f8cf40aa798c4f9d8ee85e6fe60', 0, '6f50b756815a739ba2faa2c281bf4e4f9af3fd7c', 99819, 1321259075);
```

And this one:

```
User@Host: my_db[my_db] @  [111.111.111.16]  
Thread_id: 27062326  Schema: my_db  
Query_time: 134.527582  Lock_time: 99.154168  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 45718650  Rows_affected: 37  Rows_read: 7074  
DELETE `tbl_carts`  
FROM `tbl_carts`  
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_sessions`  
ON `tbl_carts`.`id` = `tbl_sessions`.`cart_id`  
WHERE `tbl_sessions`.`cart_id` IS NULL;
```

The table structures are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_sessions` (  
  `session_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
  `cart_id` int(10) default NULL,  
  `fingerprint` varchar(40) default '',  
  `expires` int(11) default '0',  
  `member_id` int(10) default NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`session_id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

CREATE TABLE `tbl_carts` (  
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `cart` text,  
  `timestamp` int(11) default '0',  
  `url` text,  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=41635 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: add an index to tbl_session(cart_id). It would help the deletion. But something else is wrong. Are your disks healthy? Does a bigger gunzip perform ok?

Comment: Will have to check the health status of the disks with our host. The MySQL servers are located on other machines in the cloud server environment so the potential latency for remote database requests can't be helping either. I'm not familiar with gunzip. Is this part of the database import/exporting process? I can see how a compression problem could have an effect on the load-balanced MySQL servers. If the compression fails or it takes too long to prepare the data for cloning to the other database servers then the tables in question will stay locked for longer and cause timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a locking issue... The INSERT statements are taking too long and that causes the SELECT to wait for them to finish (SELECT lock time is 99 seconds). I don't think that switching from Innodb to MyISAM will increase the speed (if the Innodb is not misconfigured).

Also I would not say that it is a disk problem as that would affect also all other queries to other tables...

How many rows does have the sessions table? I suppose you don't have million active sessions... Index on VARCHAR is of course slower, but should not be that slow...

But for Innodb it is generally advised not to have big primary indexes, because they are used for many lookups... And 4-byte INT is faster than 32-byte VARCHAR (or 64-byte in case it is not BINARY and default charset is utf8). So I would recommend to delete the PRIMARY KEY (that will cause that Innodb engine will make an internal primary key of type INT) and make a UNIQUE key on the `session_id` field. That should make the INSERTs faster, because it will just increment the primary key and check the uniqueness of `session-id`.